# Getting started with Oracle application development

Tags: java, oracle

I am not sure if I am getting in a little too deep but I have decided i'd like to learn how to develop applications built using the Oracle technology stack.

I don't come from a programming background (I have always been on the business side) but I love that no matter what problem you encounter, you can almost always solve it with a program of some description (i know 'program' is probably the wrong word there but hopefully you know what I mean).

So my questions:

1. Given I have no programming experience, should I be trying to start with something else?
2. If Oracle is an ok start, from what I can ascertain i'll need to get a fair grasp of Java as well. Where should I start?

Im not necessarily looking for the quickest way, but I do want to make sure that whatever I do gives me a good understanding of what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any object-oriented programming background, I suggest you should start out by getting familiar with basic OO concept. I recommend reading this book "Head First Java" [http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Java-Kathy-Sierra/dp/0596009208](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208) and the official java tutorial - http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reallybigindex.html

After you get the idea and basic concept on object-oriented programming and java. You can move yourself to use any technology including Oracle technology stack and other OO language such as python and C#.

Answer (score 0):

As natch3z has mentioned, if you don't have a programming background it might be worthwhile starting a little simpler than the oracle tech stack.

By Oracle tech stack, I am assuming using things like oc4j, ADF, oracle DB etc all within Oracle's JDeveloper IDE.  Even though technologies like this can be powerful and achieve what you want, it might be a little overwhelming for a beginner.

It might be a little more advantageous to start off with something like the Eclipse IDE and work you way through some simple tutorials.  There's nothing worse than starting with something difficult and getting discouraged due to being overwhelmed.

Answer (score 0):

Why Java ? More specifically, what sort of stuff are you aiming to develop ?

For web applications, you could look at PHP. Oracle also has a web development/runtime environment in the database, called [Application Express](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/application_express/html/what_is_apex.html). That's a pretty simple way to get started in developing data oriented web applications. It is all part of a single install with their free [XE](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html) edition.

Comment: It just seemed from everything that I read that Java was fairly heavily intertwined with Oracle's offerings. I have looked at APEX however I am wanting to make sure what ever I learn isn't too specific. If I learn using APEX, can I use what I have learn with other parts of Oracle's stack?

Comment: Java isn't particularly intertwined with Oracle database. However a lot of Enterprise development is done with Java, and the latest version of Oracle's EBusiness software is done with Java. 
Java runtime is installed on most PCs now (as opposed to languages like PHP or Python). If you want to learn how to program, Java can be a good choice. If you want to learn databases, Oracle can be a good choice. The two just don't necessarily overlap.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle questions you could try posting on the new dedicated Oracle stack exchange site, http://www.oracleoverflow.com/, maintained by Simple Talk Publishing.